# Get nearest element in SVG using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, svg

I am using [Verovio](http://www.verovio.org/index.xhtml) to render sheet music to SVG and display them in a browser.

For my project I need to get the nearest SVG element of a certain type to the mouse pointer. Calculating the distances for all elements (e.g. using d3.js) is not a viable solution due to performance issues.

Is there any elegant way to do this?

Comment: Draw a transparent larger shape above each real element and then check which of the transparent shapes are directly below the mouse useing elementFromPoint.

Comment: What about using `.mousemove()` to get mouse position and `.position()` to get element position?

Comment: @RobertLongson +1 quite clever utilizing the browser... you should write this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Quadtree Nearest Neighbour Algorithm.

http://bl.ocks.org/patricksurry/6478178

The performance is quite good.